# DynamicModule with intermediate expressions

Tags: dynamic, scoping

I am trying to generalize a `Manipulate` construct into a `DynamicModule` one to try and include smoother controls, but I seem to be running afoul of `Dynamic`'s compartmentalization of my intermediate variables inside what used to be a `Module`.

More specifically, I used to have a construct of the form

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{y},
  y = f[x];
  {x, g[y]}
  ]
 , {x, 0, 1}]
```

including (a large number of) intermediate expressions like `y=f[x]`, and which produced output like

[image]

I now want to move control of the variable `x` into the `Module` - essentially, into a [`LocatorPane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocatorPane.html) command - but I don't know what the correct translation of the code above should be. My naive attempt is to so something like

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 y = f[x];
 {Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x], Dynamic[g[y]]}
 ]
```

and this produces no errors but the output inside `g` fails to update:

[image]

What is the correct generalization of the `Manipulate[Module[ ... ] ]` combination? I have tried inserting `Dynamic` commands in all possible combinations but I cannot seem to get them right. I know the answer is probably fairly basic, but I'm also a bit lost in the maze of tutorials for these commands.

Obviously, simply doing `{Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x], Dynamic[f[g[y]]]}` is not an option in my case. The intermediate calculations `f[x]` are quite a few and very verbose, and the 'displayable' function `g[y]` is actually several rather long and slow plotting commands. I need to do the central bit of the computation only once, and I do not want to repeat myself in giving it to the plotting commands.

What am I missing here? It feels very basic but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mimic `Manipulate`, wrap the body in `Dynamic`:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 Dynamic[
  y = f[x];
  {Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x], Dynamic[g[y]]}]
 ]
```

(It's what `Manipulate` does.)

But putting the `y` code inside its own `Dynamic` is a little cleaner:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 {Slider[Dynamic[x]],
  Dynamic[x],
  Dynamic[y = f[x]; Dynamic[g[y]]]}
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do something like:

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
  {Slider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x], Dynamic[g[y]]}
  , 
 Initialization :> (y = f[x];)]
```

for full control I would avoid using `Manipulate`. When you don't know what's going on, use `Print` for example. Let's focus on your `Manipulate` code:

```
Manipulate[Module[{y}, Print[1]; y = f[x];
  {x, g[y]}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

If you move the slider you are flooded by print. Now you know that your example works because definition of `y` is reevaluated at each update.